# How can I connect a force sensitive resistor to a vibration motor via Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, motor

Please forgive me if my knowledge is limited--still very new to this!

I'm currently working on my senior thesis for my Industrial Design program and I'm struggling to figure out the components and code I need to link a FSR and a vibration motor. Basically the idea would be that high pressure on the FSR would equate to high vibration on the motor and vice versa so you could get variable intensity based off of how hard you squeeze the sensor. I've looked up a lot of different circuit diagrams for using a vibration motor with an Arduino and many of them seem to indicate that I will need a 1N4001 Diode, a 2N2222 NPN Transistor, a 1KΩ Resistor, and a 0.1µF ceramic capacitor. I'm currently using the Arduino UNO R3 and I don't want to fry it so before I go tinkering too much I wanted to ask what you all might do to achieve what I'm aiming to do.

Thank you and I appreciate any and all feedback!

Comment: When asking about circuits it's best to include a circuit diagram. The editor here includes a tool that lets you draw them as part of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the Arduino at all.  If the force on the FSR increases resistance then you just need to invert that value and apply it the motor.  To be honest this sounds more like an electronics problem so you might want to get this moved to SE EE.

Comment: Can you provide a data sheet for the fsr?